# Copy top level folder structure without copying files in linux

Tags: linux

I would like to copy a folder structure (without the files), but only the top level folders. That is, with my source:

```
folder a
 * folder 1
 * folder 2
   * folder X
folder b
 * folder 3
folder c
```

I want my destination to simply be:

```
folder a
folder b
folder c
```

How can I do this in Linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU `find`, which supports `-printf`, and GNU `xargs`, which supports `-r`:

```
find /source/path -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '/target/path/%f\0' | xargs -r -0 -- mkdir --
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do this:

```
for dir in *; do mkdir /path/to/"$dir"; done
```

This assumes that you want to copy *everything* in the current directory and that all you have in that directory are the target folders, no files. It will collect all names in the current directory (`*`) and run `mkdir` to create empty folders of that name in the target path.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve ownership, etc. (at least it works on CentOS 7):

```
find /source/path -maxdepth 1 -type d | cpio -pdvm /destination/path
```